# Find a Google Maps location closest to my point

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm creating an app where a user can go to a landmark that google maps isn't aware of such as a cave. When they leave the landmark, their trail is recorded but then recording automatically stops once they arrive at a location that can be searched for in google maps (highway, trail in the woods, etc).

So, **I need to find a Google Maps location closest to my point** (in principle, just the distance to it would be enough).

I would start recording when it's farther than a threshold, then stop recording once some (possibly other) location is closer than (another) threshold.

How can I do that with Android's Google Maps API?

Comment: Clarified the question. Please also show your research: what did you already look through, what did you consider?

Comment: I don't understand what the definition of a "Google Maps location" is. Why can't you just determine the latitude and longitude of the landmark? Also, what are you planning on recording? GPS and WiFi location techniques are not expected to work in caves.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific. The user will take a picture of the landmark and then they will walk back to the starting point. I want it to be able to automatically detect that they've gotten to a place that can be searched for in Google maps and stop recording. Then google maps will be able to give them directions to that point, and we will be able to give them directions to the landmark.